# cudnn: CUDNN_SOFTMAX_FAST ouputing NaN when CUDNN_SOFTMAX_ACCURATE workings fine

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, cudnn, softmax

Using certain sets of float values for cudnnSoftmaxForward produces NaN outputs when the setting CUDNN_SOFTMAX_FAST is used instead of CUDNN_SOFTMAX_ACCURATE. Does anyone know why this is happening? Is this a bug in the library?

```
cudnnHandle_t lib;
cudnnCreate(&lib);
int count = 10;
size_t size = count * sizeof(float);

float examples[] = {
    95.094505f,
    -600.288879f,
    85.621284f,
    72.220154f,
    70.099487f,
    43.734470f,
    69.538422f,
    69.705490f,
    20.752966f,
    81.020088f
};

float* cexamples;
cudaMalloc(&cexamples, size);
cudaMemcpy(cexamples, examples, size, cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cudnnTensorDescriptor_t tExamples;
cudnnCreateTensorDescriptor(&tExamples);
cudnnSetTensor4dDescriptor(tExamples, cudnnTensorFormat_t::CUDNN_TENSOR_NCHW, cudnnDataType_t::CUDNN_DATA_FLOAT, 1, count, 1, 1);

float one = 1;
float zero = 0;

cudnnSoftmaxForward(lib, cudnnSoftmaxAlgorithm_t::CUDNN_SOFTMAX_FAST, cudnnSoftmaxMode_t::CUDNN_SOFTMAX_MODE_INSTANCE, &one, tExamples, cexamples, &zero, tExamples, cexamples);

cudaMemcpy(examples, cexamples, size, cudaMemcpyKind::cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    printf("%f  ", examples[i]);
}
```

Here are the results using CUDNN_SOFTMAX_FAST:

[image]

Here are the results using CUDNN_SOFTMAX_ACCURATE:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your problem is caused by overflow i.e. you (somewhere in the process) have a value that becomes too big to be a `float`.

`CUDNN_SOFTMAX_FAST` just run without checking whether an overflow occured or not. On the other hand `CUDNN_SOFTMAX_ACCURATE` avoids it (using subtraction).

CUDNN returns NaN on overflow (note that 'standart' C would probably not behave like this)

What I could suggest:

- Use smaller values (why not using [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)) ?)
- Try to use bigger types (looks naive but maybe it would be ok)
- Just set `CUDNN_SOFTMAX_ACCURATE`

Hope this helps

`pltrdy`